# Função javascript que receba três números como parâmetros e retorne o maior

Tags: javascript

Preciso criar um função que receba três números como parâmetros e retorne o maior deles. Se dois ou os três forem iguais, mostra o valor igual.

Consegui fazer a comparação, porém falta mostrar que se tiver um valor repetido ele mostra esse valor.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fsg9xz99/)

```
var n1 = parseFloat(prompt("Digite um número:"));
var n2 = parseFloat(prompt("Digite um número:"));
var n3 = parseFloat(prompt("Digite um número:"));

function maiorDosTres() {
    var a = Array.prototype.sort.call(arguments);
    alert( "O maior número é: " + a[a.length - 1] + " e o menor é: " + a[0]);
}

maiorDosTres(n1, n2, n3);Q
```

Comment: "Se dois ou os três forem iguais, mostra o valor igual" - Esta premissa acaba por não afetar em nada o objetivo original. Se mostrar o maior, tanto será valido para elementos todos diferentes, como para qualquer quantidade de elementos maiores iguais.

Comment: Ou o objetivo é saber se o maior elemento é repetido ou unico ?

Answer (score 6):

[**Math.max()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) - retorna o maior de um ou mais números

```js
var n1 = parseFloat(prompt("Digite um número:"));
var n2 = parseFloat(prompt("Digite um número:"));
var n3 = parseFloat(prompt("Digite um número:"));

var numbers = [n1, n2, n3];

var sorted_arr = numbers.sort();  
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) {
    if (sorted_arr[i + 1] == sorted_arr[i]) {
        results.push(sorted_arr[i]);
    }
}
var repetido = (results[0]);

if (results!=""){
  console.log(repetido);
}else{
  console.log(Math.max(n1, n2, n3));
}
```

Comment: E se tiverem números iguais, tipo 1,1, 2? vai retornar 2

Comment: @sam, 2 é maior que o primeiro 1 e também maior que o segundo 1 :)

Comment: Mas deveria retornar 1 porque tem igual. Veja a pergunta: "_Se dois ou os três forem iguais, mostra o valor igual._"

Comment: @sam, mas onde é que você viu que se for 1,1, 2, não retorna 1? :)

Answer (score -2):

Como são apenas 3 números e caso haja algum repetido que *retorne ele*, neste caso basta apenas que dois números sejam iguais para atender a esse critério.

Explicações no código:

```js
var n1 = parseFloat(prompt("Digite um número:"));
var n2 = parseFloat(prompt("Digite um número:"));
var n3 = parseFloat(prompt("Digite um número:"));

function maiorDosTres() {
    var a = [].sort.call(arguments);
    var maior = a[2]; // seleciona o último número
    var menor = a[0] // seleciona o primeiro número
    var msg = maior == a[1] || menor == a[1] ? // se o primeiro ou o último for igual ao segundo
      "Número repetido: "+ (maior == a[1] ? maior : menor) // mostra essa mensagem selecionando o que foi igual
      :
      "O maior número é: " + maior + " e o menor é: " + menor; // ou então mostra essa mensagem quando não houve repetidos

    alert(msg);
}

maiorDosTres(n1, n2, n3);
```